# Validating UserInput is not Negative using an ArrayList

Tags: java, validation, arraylist

Im just learning basic stuff at this point, however I have raked my brain trying to take user input into an ArrayList below and validating that that input is not a negative number.  I may be over thinking.. But let me know if you can help.

Thanks

```
public static ArrayList<Double> readcuinput()
{
    ArrayList<Double> cuinput;
    cuinput = new ArrayList<Double>();
    boolean IsNegative;

    do{
        IsNegative = false;
        System.out.println("Enter value, "
        + "Q to quit: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            cuinput.add(in.nextDouble());
            for (int i = 0; i < cuinput.size();i++)
            { 
                if (cuinput.get(i) < 0)
                {
                    System.err.println("Error: Must not be a Negative Value");
                    IsNegative = true;
                }
            }
         }
      }while(IsNegative = true);
    return cuinput;
```

Comment: I mean, do you have a particular question about this?

Comment: Change `=` to `==` in the `while` condition.

Comment: Or git rid of the `==` altogether and just keep `isNegative`.

Comment: like this: `while(IsNegative);`

Comment: You're really overdoing it. A `for` in a `while` in a `do-while` is really too much. You don't need the `for`, as you could simple check for the value before adding it to the list. Also, if you do this, its obvious that every value inserted would be non-negative, so that checking for all values in `for` is pointless then.

Answer (score 0):

First change `=` to `==` in the `while` condition.

Second, if the last input was **negative**, delete it from the array:

```
...
if (cuinput.get(i) < 0) {
    System.err.println("Error: Must not be a Negative Value");
    IsNegative = true;
    cuinput.remove(i); // ADD THIS
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks you guys aree the best.  works like a charm.  Is there a simple fix in my loop order to prompt the user to re-enter a value if they get the Error vs having to enter Q to re-start.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified

```
public static ArrayList<Double> readcuinput() {
    ArrayList<Double> cuinput= new ArrayList<Double>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        double value = in.nextDouble();
        if (value < 0) {
            System.err.println("Error: Must not be a Negative Value");
            break;
        }
        cuinput.add(value);
    }
    return cuinput;
}
```